# Use Beanshell Assertion inside a Critical Section Controller

Tags: jmeter, test-plan

I'm trying to use Beanshell Assertion inside a Critical Section Controller, but it seems to be ignored. Does someone know why is this behaviour? have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter Assertions are executed only in context of the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), if there is no sampler which generates a [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) in the Assertion's [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) - it will not be executed.

Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) on next available opportunity

Comment: Thank you vert much!

Answer (score 1):

> [assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions) apply to all samplers which are in their [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

> Assertion, for instance, is hierarchical in the test tree. If its parent is a request, then it is applied to that request. If its parent is a Controller, then it affects all requests that are descendants of that Controller.